# Rails 4 - concern resources issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an issue with Rails 4 concerns on my application

```
concern :common do
  resources :comments
  resources :categories
  resources :tags
end

resources :articles, concerns: :common
resources :messages, concerns: :common
```

Problem I was facing is that I want to add specific controller actions(Ex create,edit) for resource messages through concerns. I don't know how to pass actions in concern. Please help me to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optional arguments can be passed into concerns through resource definitions

```
concern :common do |options|
  resources :comments, options
  resources :categories, options
  resources :tags, options
end

resources :articles, concerns: :common
resources :messages do
  concerns: :common, only: :create,:edit
end
```

I hope it would solve the problems.

Comment: How can i handle similar logic in app/concerns/common.rb